# Unwanted hyperlinks appear on the website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Unwanted hyperlinks are getting added on my website's text content.

URL: `http://www.empoweringparents.com/my-child-refuses-to-do-homework-heres-how-to-stop-the-struggle.php#`

Please check the 10th point, you can see links starting with " rolex replica watches...".

Iam not sure whether someone hacking the text content or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about webmaster topics.

Comment: How is this a programming problem? There is a million reasons this could be happening.

Comment: This is unrelated to programming and should be closed.

Comment: Meh, are you drunk, man.

Comment: are you promoting your site here?

Comment: It's hacked. Turn off the interwebz.

Comment: I don't see the links that you are referring to. I suspect you have some [advertisement injecting spyware on your computer.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mmpc/archive/2013/06/20/ad-injection-and-you-how-adware-gets-on-your-computer.aspx)

Comment: Please give us a link to the website. More than likely a bot broke into your server and added code output to all your *.php files. I had that happen once.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, your website is okay. You probably have a spyware of some sort on the browser that adds "related ads" to the content you see.

Comment: Both answers are a good possibility.

Comment: I've seen this happen where someone's router was hacked...  A Coworker... And he thought something was wrong with the site we were working on.

Answer (score 1):

Always save backups of your website for later restoration. You should check the rights of files on your servers, `chmod` everything so strangers cannot read, write, run what they shouldn't. Also make sure, that your website isn't vulnerable to XSS attacks. (SQL injection is not playing here, so this time probably you can skip checking such issues)